# VBA Excel Macro SelectSingleNode returns nothing

Tags: excel, vba, macros

> My very first venture with excel macro, I have written code to parse a
>   web service response and I would like to update tag values in
>   individual cells in excel.
>
> Following is the excerpt of my XML (a huge web service response)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
      <bm:getTransactionResponse xmlns:bm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1">
         <bm:status>
            <bm:success>true</bm:success>
            <bm:message>Wed Apr 06 09:04:32 UTC 2016 - Successfully processed API for test1</bm:message>
         </bm:status>
         <bm:transaction>
            <bm:category>data</bm:category>
            <bm:action>add</bm:action>
            <bm:id>1111</bm:id>
            <bm:process_var_name>xvgfdr</bm:process_var_name>
            <bm:buyer_company_name>test1</bm:buyer_company_name>
            <bm:supplier_company_name>test1</bm:supplier_company_name>
            <bm:step_var_name>waitingForInternalApproval</bm:step_var_name>
            <bm:last_document_number>2</bm:last_document_number>
            <bm:date_added>2016-04-04 12:14:57</bm:date_added>
            <bm:date_modified>2016-04-06 09:04:18</bm:date_modified>
            <bm:data_xml>
               <bm:transaction bm:bs_id="11111" bm:buyer_company_name="test1" bm:buyer_user_name="someone" bm:currency_pref="GBP" bm:data_type="0" bm:document_name="Transaction" bm:document_number="1" bm:document_var_name="transaction" bm:process_var_name="XXX_1" bm:supplier_company_name="test1">
                  <bm:_document_number>1</bm:_document_number>
                  <bm:createdBy_t>SomeOne</bm:createdBy_t>
                  <bm:_price_book_var_name>_default</bm:_price_book_var_name>
                  <bm:createdDate_t>2016-04-04 00:00:00</bm:createdDate_t>
                  <bm:currency_t>INR</bm:currency_t>
                  <bm:_customer_t_first_name/>
                  <bm:_customer_t_last_name/>
                  <bm:_customer_t_company_name>Test Account</bm:_customer_t_company_name>
```

I am trying to fetch the  Value of Tag `<bm:_customer_t_company_name>`

> Below is the code, I've been using.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

                'Set and instantiate our working objects
                    Dim Req As Object
                    Dim sEnv As String
                    Dim Resp As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
                    Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    Set Resp = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")                   
                    With Req

                    .Open "Post", "https://XXXX.com/", False                    
                    Dim Pwd As String
                    Pwd = Range("D8").Value


                    Dim QuoteId As String
                    QuoteId = Range("D9").Value

                    ' SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
                     sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Header>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=""UsernameToken-2"">"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <wsse:Username>" & Range("D7").Value & "</wsse:Username>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <wsse:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"">" & Pwd & "</wsse:Password>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  </wsse:UsernameToken>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  </wsse:Security>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  </soapenv:Header>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Body>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "   <bm:getTransaction>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "    <bm:transaction>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "    <bm:id>" & Range("D9").Value & "</bm:id>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "   </bm:transaction>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "   </bm:getTransaction>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "  </soapenv:Body>"
                     sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"                    
                    ' Send SOAP Request
        .send (sEnv)       

        Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

        End With
        If Resp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No XML"
        End If
        With Resp

        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"""
        Dim strName As String
        If .SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name") Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No Node"
        End If
        strName = .SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name").Text
        MsgBox strName
    End With

  'clean up code
    Set Req = Nothing
    Set Resp = Nothing
Range("A1").Value = "DONE"
End Sub
```

> .SelectSingleNode("//soap:Body") works fine.
>                    the .SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name") always returns Nothing when I test my code. So is the
>
> > .SelectSingleNode("//bm:getTransactionResponse"), returns nothing.
> >
> > Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Here is a screenshot of full XML structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26aFK.jpg)

Comment: i have not tested this, may be this will help you. Add namespace to xmlnamespacemanager and pass that to selectsingle node for ex: i assigned namespace to abc then .SelectSingleNode("//abc:bm:_customer_t_company_name"

Comment: Thanks Karthik for the quick resposne.
Changing the code to the below giving a runtime error.

.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:abc=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"""
        Dim strName As String
        If .SelectSingleNode("//abc:bm:_customer_t_company_name") Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No Node"
        End If
        strName = .SelectSingleNode("//abc:bm:_customer_t_company_name").Text

Expected Token 'EOF' found ':'
/abc:bm->:<-_customer_t_company_name

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with the code as you presented it. You should examine the XML that the web service is actually returning to make sure that it has the tag that you're looking for.

I reduced your example to the following VBA Sub, which runs without error.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xml
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xml.LoadXML "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""> <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""/> <soap:Body> <bm:getTransactionResponse xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1""> <bm:status> <bm:success>true</bm:success> <bm:message>Wed Apr 06 09:04:32 UTC 2016 - Successfully processed API for test1</bm:message> </bm:status> <bm:transaction> <bm:category>data</bm:category> <bm:action>add</bm:action> <bm:id>1111</bm:id> <bm:process_var_name>xvgfdr</bm:process_var_name> <bm:buyer_company_name>test1</bm:buyer_company_name> <bm:supplier_company_name>test1</bm:supplier_company_name> <bm:step_var_name>waitingForInternalApproval</bm:step_var_name> <bm:last_document_number>2</bm:last_document_number> <bm:date_added>2016-04-04 12:14:57</bm:date_added> <bm:date_modified>2016-04-06 09:04:18</bm:date_modified> <bm:data_xml> <bm:transaction bm:bs_id=""11111"" bm:buyer_company_name=""test1"" bm:buyer_user_name=""someone"" bm:currency_pref=""GBP"" bm:data_type=""0"" bm:document_name=""Transaction"" bm:document_number=""1"" bm:document_var_name=""transaction"" bm:process_var_name=""XXX_1"" bm:supplier_company_name=""test1""> <bm:_document_number>1</bm:_document_number> <bm:createdBy_t>SomeOne</bm:createdBy_t> <bm:_price_book_var_name>_default</bm:_price_book_var_name> <bm:createdDate_t>2016-04-04 00:00:00</bm:createdDate_t> <bm:currency_t>INR</bm:currency_t> <bm:_customer_t_first_name/> <bm:_customer_t_last_name/> <bm:_customer_t_company_name>Test Account</bm:_customer_t_company_name> </bm:transaction> </bm:data_xml> </bm:transaction> </bm:getTransactionResponse> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>"

    xml.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"""

    Debug.Print xml.SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name").Text
End Sub
```

Output is `Test Account`.

Comment: Hi Tmdean, Thank you so much for your inputs.I tested by removing the SelectSingleNode lined and added the below 
With Resp        
        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"""
        WScript.Echo Resp.SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name").Text
End With

Comment: the line WScript.... gives the runtime error "Object variable or with block variable not set".I have used Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText in my code, is it equivalent to  xml.LoadXML "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap..."  ?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent. In my script, I'm loading the SOAP response XML directly into an DOMDocument60 object using LoadXML instead of doing a web request like you are. Since my code works, it appears that the problem is with the XML output that you're receiving from the web service and doesn't have anything to do with SelectSingleNode or XML namespaces.

Comment: If you want to run my VBScript example in Excel, just change WScript.Echo to Debug.Print

Comment: Still the same error with the below code 
"Object variable or with block variable not set" on the SelectSingleNode line.
With Resp
        
        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/XXXCLD/commerce/ZZZYYY_PPP_1"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"""
         
         Debug.Print .SelectSingleNode("//bm:_customer_t_company_name").Text
        
    End With
 
 I checked the web service response by saving it in a textbox in the work sheet , It's the same I have given in my post too.

Comment: I rewrote my script in VBA so you should be able to run it in Excel now. If the XML you included in the question is the actual XML, it's truncated and missing a bunch of end tags. I had assumed you truncated it yourself for brevity but maybe not.

Comment: You are write, I truncated the response XML before pasting it in th epost. As you can see the XML does have the tag <bm:_customer_t_company_name>Test Account</bm:_customer_t_company_name> 
 in it. I am not sure why it is still giving Nothing when I check the tag. I am able to fetch soap:Body tag successfully , but not any of its children.

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the Full XML in my post , the tags I need to fetch are the children of highligted tag in the screenshot bm:data_xml/   bm:transaction